# Python: Stream mp4 files to webcam

Tags: python, virtual-camera

I want to stream mp4 videos to a virtual webcam using python.
I have tried using pyvirtualcam with the following code:

```
def play_video(path):
    vid = skvideo.io.vread(path)
    print(vid.shape)
    for frame in vid:
        cam.send(frame)
        cam.sleep_until_next_frame()
    
    
with pyvirtualcam.Camera(width=1080, height=1920, fps=60, print_fps=True) as cam:
    print(f'Using virtual camera: {cam.device}')
    while True:
        play_video("final.mp4")
```

This works, however it is so slow that it is unusable (running on a very powerful PC).
So my question is, if there is any more elegant way of streaming videos to a virtual camera.

Thanks